# How to update icon of a .bin file - not working anymore since 22

Tags: 22.04, icons, .desktop, binary

On Ubuntu 22, Wayland disabled:
I have a .bin file that has no icon. In 16.04 I could create a launcher (.desktop) file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/local/bin/myapp
Name=MYAPP
Icon=/home/pa/my_icon.ico
```

That would create a "shortcut" on the desktop using that icon and also, when launching the application, would use that image as a icon for the application in the dock.

Now, if I do the same, I still get the launcher using that icon:

[image: Desktop Icon]

but the app in the dock still uses the default icon:

[image: Dock Icon]

I also tried changing the binaries icon via the properties tab to no effect.
[image: properties]